# Cordova app not displaying correctly on iOS devices

Tags: ios, cordova

I am working on an cordova application. I am using xcode V9.2 and running my cordova application on iPad with v11.1.1.I am seeing a black strip at the top of the screen. I googled for this issue and as per majority of suggestions tried using

1.)viewport-fit=cover in my viewport tag.

2.)

```
body{
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

but the above suggestion are not working in my case.Need some help!

[image: Notice the top of the ipad screen]

Comment: Did you do both? try with only the first one

Comment: viewport-fit=cover worked for me! after digging out more in my application code i noticed some code was causing the problem and preventing viewport-fit=cover functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use in my app:

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:  100%;
}
```